# Number Theory - Prove $n^2$ and $n-1$ are coprime

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, coprime

In my foundations of math class we have just finished our section on number theory.  I am having a really hard time with the questions involving co-primality, gcd's, and Bezout's identity.

The question I'm working on now asks us to prove $gcd(n^2,n-1)=1$ for all $n>=1$

I know that the above implies $1=an^2 + b(n-1)$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I seem to be just running into dead ends and gaps in logic/knowledge.

Comment: Hint: $n-1$ divides $n^2 -1$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Hint. Given $n$, find values of $a$ and $b$ that work for that $n$. That will imply the gcd is $1$. (In your question you have the implication backwards. It's true that way but not useful here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Bezout's identity.

Let $p$ be a prime dividing $n^2$. Then $p$ divides $n$. If $p$ divided $n-1$ , then $p$ would divide $1$.

Comment: To be sure I understand completely, this comes from: if a divides b and a divides c, then a divides bx+cy for any integers x,y. correct?

Comment: @user502067, the last part, yes.

Answer (score 1):

$n^2-(n+1)(n-1)=1-n^2+n^2=1$ implies the result.